# Delegate Incoming Traffic to the correct web server

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I am fairly educated in basic networking and Unix but there is one piece of the puzzle that I am missing to finish my home virtual network. I have a physical server running prox-mox that has 3 different virtual servers running the latest version of Ubuntu server. I need to figure out a way to delegate the incoming traffic to my main server with different web address to the correct virtual server. I have succeeded in doing this using a complex line of Apache code but it's not ideal what so ever. I even drew this picture to help explain what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

There are so many different aspects of this project that I did not know where to ask (Proxmox, apache, stack exchange, or even, other smaller forums.) so I thought I could start here. I would love suggestions or help!

Comment: Look into something like [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) that can do both HTTP reverse proxy and load balancing all in one.

Comment: @Terrance I am looking into that option now. It seems like it 'may' be slightly overkill for what it is I am trying to do. But I am going to give it a test on a vm and see what results I get.

Comment: You can use nginx to reverse proxy your sites. https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/ . Syntax is trivial - proxypass www.site1.com -> 1.1.1.1 proxypass www.site2.com -> 2.2.2.2 . You you have to provide more details if you want someone to write the config for you. nginx is light weight and easy to configure.

Comment: @Panther so I have Nginx installed. I need "maxkulik.net" to go to "192.168.1.30" and I need "ftp.maxkulik.net" to go to 192.168.1.32". The IP address of where Nginx is installed to is "192.168.1.36".

Comment: As far as I know, you can not use nginx for ftp. There are discussions and possible solutions at these links - https://superuser.com/questions/957573/ftp-proxy-using-nginx and https://serverfault.com/questions/700820/reverse-proxy-multiple-internal-ftp-servers and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472363/how-to-reroute-sftp-traffic-via-nginx

Comment: @Panther I am actually not using it for FTP. I am just using a personal sub domain of my own as an example. I am just looking for a proof of concept at the moment.